# Upgrading from Next 9 to Next 11 facing issues with webpack, Harmony-module.js not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

[image]

Trying to upgrade my Next 9 application to Next 11, there are tons of vulnerabilities found. How do I fix this issue also which is a right approach to go about for upgrading the application to next 11

Comment: Can you post your `next.config.js` and `package.json` files? And try regenerating your lock file (just delete `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and run `yarn` or `npm install`?

Comment: Deleting node-module & next build folder along with reinstalling the package helped to clear this issue